# Mapping data flows, schema for parametrised sink and source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I am currently trying to rewrite some of my SSIS packages to ADF mapping data flows. I want to use parameters in order to avoid creating hundreds of different sinks and sources. However, I have encountered one problem on the way.

Let's take one sink as an example:
[image]

[image]

It doesn't have any schema defined. Then if I try to use it in my dataflow(and provide a value for my parameter), I get:

[image]

I can avoid this error by hardcoding schema on my sink but then this schema is used wherever I decide to use this sink, so I cannot really use it mutiple times...

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are attempting to maximize reuse of a single data flow, you should consider just using auto-mapping for the sink and set "allow schema drift" to on so that you can gain maximum flexibility in your mappings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried that. However, it still gives me the very same error.

Comment: Do you have a schema defined in your sink? If you clear the schema, this should work.

Comment: Actually your solution has worked in most cases, I've had some naming inconsistencies, my mistake. I still have one sink that doesn't work no matter what, so I have just created a separate data source with one hard-coded schem for that...